# jQuery re-size image to fit container on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing an application here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwuliger/q5yvW/2/

What is happening is once you drop an image into one of the containers it will re-size the image based on the size of said container. I added a rotation piece to this so that when a user clicks on the image once it is in the container it will rotate.

What I need help with is re-sizing the image again to fit within the container after a rotation has occurred. You can see a live example of this working from the link above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the code but it seems once you have the logic the code should be easy looking at the fiddle behavior

when you click image inside of a box
check box width and change image width if needed, then check if image height is greater than box height, if not then done. if height of image is bigger than box height, then resize according to height

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when your image was rotated it's width and height hadn't switched. http://jsfiddle.net/q5yvW/14/

Your algorithm could work fine if image params were switching after rotation on 90 degrees.

```
200x150 - 0 degrees
150x200 - 90 degrees
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking also but the problem is I need to keep the aspect ratio. I cannot skew the image to fit.